# How to create a dynamic url with the @ symbol

Tags: javascript, next.js

How would I create a dynamic route in Next.js with the @ symbol?

For example localhost:3000/@some_username

I know you can create dynamic routes within the pages folder but how would I do it with just the @ symbol and no / afterward like the above example.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a prefix by defining a rewrite in your **next.config.js**.

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/@:username',
        destination: '/users/:username'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This redirects all /@{username} routes to /users/{username}.

Some more information about rewrites in nextjs can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the standard dynamic routing in [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). You don't need rewrites.

Name the file or folder `[@:username]` in your root directory.

There are a few ways to do this:

App directory as folder named `[@:username]`

`/app/[@:username]/page.js`

Pages directory as file named `[@:username].js`

`/pages/[@:username].js`

Pages directory as folder named `[@:username]`

`/pages/[@:username]/index.js`

The param can be access the query param on the page like

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const { query } = useRouter();  
const username = query["@:username"];
```

Comment: For this, I get an error saying that it's not valid as a file or folder nameaaaaaa

Comment: This format works and we use it at my company. Did you name the file `[@:username].js` or the folder `[@:username]`. You don't include the slashes or anything - I put it up there to show the full file/folder path.

Comment: I got an error while following the `/app/[@:username]/page.js` part. or it's not working.

Next.js 13 using App Router

Comment: This doesn't actually limit the dynamic route to segments starting with `@`. This just causes the dynamic segment variable to be named `"@:username"`.